# Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, url-routing

I'm currently getting this error when trying to render my view from my routes folder

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory Website\gaming-galaxy\views"
```

Here's my project tree inside of the gaming-galaxy project folder

```
gaming-galaxy
  public_html
  - css
  - fonts
  - img 
  routes
  - index.mjs
  src
  - app.mjs
  views
  - layouts
    - layouts.ejs
  - index.ejs
  - login.ejs
  - register.ejs
  .gitignore
  package.json
```

Here's my views configuration in "**app.mjs"**

```
expressapp.set('views', path.join(__dirname , '../views'));
```

Finally, my route i'm trying to use **index.mjs**

```
import express from 'express'

import path from 'path'; 

const moduleURL = new URL(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(moduleURL.pathname);

var indexRouter = express.Router();

indexRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Attempting to render index.ejs")
    res.render('index');
    console.log("Passed test!");
})

export default indexRouter;
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I've been scratching my head at this one for hours now.

Comment: did you install and setup ejs view engine? try adding `expressapp.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Comment: @traynor Yes I setup the ejs view engine exactly like you mentioned.

Comment: probably something with __dirname, try console.log(__dirname), see what it resolves to, try changing it, try adding this to app.mjs: `import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));`

Comment: Did you even find the answer? I am having the same issue. For some reason, i can't access a specific route and only that route.